# Possible to log into facebook using username/password instead of Client UI?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way for me to use my username/password to get my Facebook authentication token instead of using the facebook UI?  I'd like to do it without any user interaction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible (and is prohibited). You can however use the UI to get an access token and request the offline_access permissions. This permission will give you a token that does not expire which you can use to do what you are attempting to do without user interaction.

Comment: How long is the token good for? Months? Years? Literally forever?

Comment: Until the user removes your application. There is no time limit for an offline_access token.